# Loop through every control in a form, with the form name defined as a variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a basic search which looks for a partial keyword match of any control in a specified form. The form name is selected via combo box and is stored as a variable.

How do I use this to loop through the controls of the selected form?

I can easily loop through the controls of the **current** form with the following:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Debug.Print ctrl.Name
Next ctrl
```

But I can't figure out how to reference an external form, with the variable essentially replacing `Me`.

I've tried using:

```
Dim ctrl as Control
Dim variableName as String
variableName = Me.cmboFormName

For each ctrl in Forms(variableName).Controls
    Debug.Print ctrl.Name
Next ctrl
```

But this just returns error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method).

Comment: Which line is throwing the error exactly?

Comment: On the `For each ctrl in Forms(variableName).Controls` line, fairly sure it's referencing `Forms(variableName).Controls` specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Dim ctrl as well, and you may have spaces in the form name:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim variableName as String

variableName = "[" & Me.cmboFormName & "]"

For Each ctrl In Forms(variableName).Controls
    Debug.Print ctrl.Name
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - ctrl is already defined, and there are no spaces in the ones I've tested so far.

Comment: Then it does work - if your combo passes a valid name of an open form.

Comment: Keyword "of an **open** form" I suppose?

Comment: Good suggestion... the form wasn't open before. Still no joy with it open though, using your code. Is the form required to be open in order to access the control names then? Could it potentially be something to do with variableName being a string, so the `Controls` property can't be found/used?

Comment: Just curious.. exactly what compile-time type does `Forms(index)` return?

Comment: No. It's very simple. The form must be open and you pass the name of it. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls 'or use your form name.
     Debug.Print ctrl.Name
Next ctrl
```

Comment: If the form has dynamic controls added at run-time, they won't *necessarily* be iterated, because this code only queries the *default instance* of the form, which may or may not be initialized and may or may not hold instance state when the loop runs. In other words it *can* work, but it's not a reliable way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is occurring on `Forms(variableName).Controls`, the instruction is doing too many things to be easily debuggable. Split it up.

Declare a variable to contain a `Form` object - note, I'm no Access dev, I usually work with Excel and MSForms, so for me that would be a `UserForm`, but I very strongly suspect that your Access forms aren't from the MSForms type library (you'd have to work pretty hard to get a `UserForm` in Access), so I'm guessing the type to use is called `Form`, but I could be wrong - will be happy to edit if corrected in a comment.

```
Dim theForm As Form
```

Now `Set` the form object:

```
Set theForm = Forms(variableName)
```

If your code didn't blow up yet, then you've successfully retrieved a form instance. That wouldn't surprise me, because if that step failed you'd probably be facing a *subscript out of range* error instead.

If your library has a `Controls` collection class, declare a variable of that type:

```
Dim theControls As Controls
```

And assign it:

```
Set theControls = theForm.Controls
```

*That* could possibly blow up with run-time error 438, if `Form` doesn't have a `Controls` member... which wouldn't really add up, given `Me.Controls` seems to work.

So go back and declare `theForm As Object`, and let VBA's late-binding magic query the object's interface, instead of working with the specific `Form` interface - again I don't know much Access, but it's fairly possible that `Me` being *a specific form type* exposes a `Controls` collection, but not the general-purpose `Form` type - VBA UI framework internals are that kind of a mess.

So, to speak COM-gibberish, by declaring it as `Object` you allow the run-time to query `IDispatch` and locate the `Controls` member.

If you can get that instruction (the `Controls` collection assignment) to run without throwing, then you should be able to iterate its content without problems.

Also keep in mind that it seems the `Forms` collection only includes *open* forms.

Comment: I actually get Error 438 on `Set theForm = Forms(variableName)` -
 interestingly I get the same error even if I replace `(variableName)` with `("<<the actual name of open form>>")`, which suggests the error may not be to do with the variable but the declaration of the form itself.

Comment: @finjo that's covered in my answer too - try declaring the form `As Object`, the assignment will work and you can inspect the runtime type with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Forms contains collection of opened forms. Unfortunately you cannot access a closed form using a variable name.

Just check whether the form is available. if not open the form either in nomal or design view and continue your code like this.

```
Dim ctrl as Control
Dim variableName as String
variableName = Me.cmboFormName

If Not (FN_FORM_ISLOADED(variableNAme)) Then
    'Open your form in desired view.
    DoCmd.OpenForm variableNAme, acNormal
End If

For each ctrl in Forms(variableName).Controls
    Debug.Print ctrl.Name
Next ctrl
```

Place this function in your public module

```
Public Function FN_FORM_ISLOADED(iFormName As String) As Boolean
    Dim I As Integer

    FN_FORM_ISLOADED = False
    For I = 0 To Forms.count - 1
        If Forms(I).name = iFormName Then
            FN_FORM_ISLOADED = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I
End Function
```